# file_exists always returns false

Tags: php, file-exists

I have a simple function to output an icon for a file type next to the file, but for some reason `file_exists()` always returns false. I have output the path that is being generated, and it clearly exists for 'default.png'. Am I missing something here?

I have tried useing the URL and the file path - both always return false.

I even set all files permisisons to 777 to test if that was the issue, but that did not work.

```
/**
 * Displays the logo for the file type passed to the function
 *
 * @param required string $file_type The file type to display an icon for
 */
function show_file_type($file_type){

    $file_types_folder = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/includes/images/file_types/';

    if(file_exists($file_types_folder.$file_type.'.png')) :
        $file_type_image = $file_types_folder.$file_type.'.png';
    elseif(file_exists($file_types_folder.'default.png')) :
        $file_type_image = $file_types_folder.'default.png';
    else :
        return false;
    endif;

    echo '<img src="'.$file_type_image.'" width="20"/>';

}
```

Comment: did you ensure that the directory containing the file was readable by your apache process?

Comment: Try validating the output of `get_bloginfo`. If template_directory isn't absolute it might not work. Also try manually checking for `/var/www/myblog/includes/...` etc , depending on your apache settings, to see if that resolved your issue.

Comment: Is $file_types_folder relative to the webserver root, or to the filesystem root?

Comment: give us an example of what $file_type might actually be

Comment: Apparently, the `$file_type` is actually the file name of the image and you are going to use it as a src for the img tag. try also using this `file_exists(realpath($file_types_folder.$file_type.'.png'))` You might be missing some URL rewrites to effectively use the absolute path as URI string of the image to point to the absolute path of the image on the server. For example, `/var/includes/images/file_types/default.png` will be translated to `http://{domain}/{path}/var/includes/images/file_types/default.png` There has to be a rewrite for that.

Comment: `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` returns the URI (www.domain.com/...), but I've also tried `ABSPATH` which is set to return the absolute path (\var\www\html\...), and neither work. Both are confirmed as correct. I have set the permissions to 777 all through the folder tree to these files, so everyone should have access.

Comment: Yes, `$file_type` is the type of document (doc, xls, pdf) for example, and I have a list of images (doc.png, xls.png, pdf.png) in the folder indicated so that I can show the file type next to the link. The paths are correct (I can output and copy and paste in to browser and it works).

Comment: Oh, and `$file_type` is a string (doc, xls, pdf, etc.).

Comment: Sorted - `realpath()` seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please don't write answers in questions. Write answers as answers.

Comment: where in my answer did it happen to be a question? I can't see any question mark on my question? Are you ridiculous?

Comment: in fact I was the one who told them that probable solution is to use realpath and is suggesting various ways on how to debug the problem @LightnessRacesinOrbit I really don't think my answer is a question but providing probable cause of the problem and probable solution to the problem.

Comment: @MelvinProtacio: What? I'm talking to the OP. He had written an answer into the question. I have edited it out.

Comment: okay.. I don't know why my answer was deleted and converted to a comment :(

Comment: Why remove it? Why not just ask if I could put it as a stand alone answer? I have no idea what was written there, and now people who may have otherwise found an answer possibly will not. If you are not going to be constructive in your moderation then don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue also. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) you should call `clearstatcache();` before calling `file_exists();` when the file is created or deleted during the same script execution. Let us know if it works!